# htaccess, MySQL DB and non-existent files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have content in a MySQL DB that I'd like to display on my home page, depending on the URL the user came from. I don't want mod_rewrite to change my URL, but rather, to do the following:

- Keep URL (ie `mysite.com/demolink2`)
- Check is the page exists, and if not, redirect to `index.php`, passing the "demolink2" variable (essentially the end of the URL string after last trailing slash)
- On the `index.php` side I'll be able to then serve up the content, but again, I don't want the user to see the URL changed to `mysite.com/index.php?id=demolink2`, but rather, have the `mysite.com/index.php` page STAY as `mysite.com/demolink2` until they click a URL within the site that leads to a real page.

Here's my current .htaccess which accomplishes the first bit; i.e. it will see if the page already exists, and if not, direct user to index, however I've done that with a rewrite.

Any help/comments would be appreciated.

**htaccess file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last line to

```
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The URL in browser will remain the same as it is rewrite (internal redirect) and not proper 3xx code redirect.

- If `mysite.com/demolink2` is requested, your script will see it as `/index.php?id=demolink2`;
- If it will be `mysite.com/hello/kitten`, then script will see `index.php?id=hello/kitten`;
- `QSA` flag is added to preserve existing query string.